# Error while calling spring controller action through URL posting

Tags: java, spring, servlets

i defined action mapping like `"@RequestMapping("/loginuser.sn")"` and try to call this from

```
url =  new URL("loginuser.sn");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url .openConnection();
```

I got this error java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

Is the code is correct?

Comment: As the exception says "MalformedURLException: no protocol". A valid url is something like `http://localhost:8080/appContext/loginuser.sn`. Depends on your setup and deployment.

Comment: Now i can post after passing whole url. Thanks @RenéLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You URL should be like  `http://hostname:portname/extra` right now you haven't specified protocol for your `URL`

```
URL url =  new URL("http://localhost:8080/base/yourpart");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url .openConnection();
```

As [`MalformedURLException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html) is thrown because protocol has not been specified i.e `http`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `http://` and hence it is not valid url. see [#URL(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)).

The error is thrown when ,

> Thrown to indicate that a malformed URL has occurred. Either no legal protocol could be found in a specification string or the string could not be parsed.